# Google Sheets - autofill per month/year

Tags: google-sheets

I created a calendar based on a tutorial I find online to where you just put in the month and year and it will automatically place the days of the month in the right area. However, when I recreated it for some reason it does not fill in certain months.

This is one of the formulas I am using `=IF(Day($A3+G8)>1, DAY($A3+G8),"").` 
When I use it for some reason it would not fill in August for 2021
This is one of the formulas for August `=IF(DAY($A66+B71)>1,DAY($A66+B71),"")`

It did it for one month in 2022 as well when I put in the month and year.

Please help!

08/29/2021 - Here is a link to my google sheet if that helps:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lm8BINPh6h4RuN1S8-0RCprFyf6wS5WwkOQUTuHHBhU/edit#gid=578097574

I wanted it to automatically fill in the dates in the correct day of the week when I change the month and year.

Comment: Attaching an example workbook with some example data would help.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(6, 7), {SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(B3, ))+WEEKDAY(B3, 2), 1, ), 
 {IFERROR(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&WEEKDAY(B3, 2)))/0); SEQUENCE(DAY(EOMONTH(B3, )), 1, B3)}}, 2, )))
```

where B3 contains `August 2021`

[image]

Comment: I tried to put in that formula changing B3 to where August 2021 is and it shows up as error.

Comment: @Needhelp can you share a copy of your sheet?